# Android: How to fetch data every 1 second, from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, timertask

I have a timertask like this one:

```
<code>           
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateGraph(.....);
        }
    },0,2000);
</code>
```

But here within the updateGraph method i want to pass the Y-value.
This Y-value is read thru another TimerTask in another activity, is this possible? Read every second from the other activity ?

/Mikael

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Passing it through Method EveryTime

Declare a public static variable and update it at Regular Frequency in Your FirstActivty in TimerTask Method

```
 public static double Y;
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 //update Y here
                updateGraph(.....);
            }
        },0,2000);
```

In Second Activity's Timer Task use

```
FirstActivity.Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep updating Y value in SharedPreference from Activity A and From Activity B inside Timer() Read the same Y value from SharedPreference.

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved! Thanks all,
used: public static values between the activites!